# How can I seed SharpRepository's InMemoryRepository?

Tags: c#, sharp-repository

As the title says, how can I seed `SharpRepository's` `InMemoryRepository` with some dummy data?

I tried this in my configuration:

```
var sharpRepositoryConfiguration = new SharpRepositoryConfiguration();
sharpRepositoryConfiguration.AddRepository(new InMemoryRepositoryConfiguration("inmemory"));
sharpRepositoryConfiguration.DefaultRepository = "inmemory";
var repo = sharpRepositoryConfiguration.GetInstance<Account>().Add(new [] { .... });

return new StructureMapDependencyResolver(sharpRepositoryConfiguration);
```

But, when the repository is resolved in my controllers, the data was not there. I was in the understanding that InMemoryRepository would function as a data store that was in memory - but is it just the case that InMemoryRepository is purely just storing data in the repositories and never pushing them to an underlying in-memory data store?

It's all very well being able to unit test and mock SharpRepository, but I can't really develop without being able to see some seeded data coming into my views :(

EDIT: I managed to do this by setting my repository implementation as a Singleton:

```
x.For<IAccountRepository>()
    .Singleton()
    .Use<SharpRepositoryAccountRepository>();
```

This is then injected into my controller. By setting it as singleton the data persists across requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `InMemoryRepositoryConfiguration` returns a **new** repository every time (see the source for the factory [here](https://github.com/SharpRepository/SharpRepository/blob/master/SharpRepository.InMemoryRepository/InMemoryConfigRepositoryFactory.cs)), so it is not suitable for dependency injection if it's set up as transient (versus singleton).

If you're trying to use this in unit tests and are trying to stay in-memory, have a look at the `CacheRepository`, I believe that will work how you'd like out of the box:

```
var sharpRepositoryConfiguration = new SharpRepositoryConfiguration();
sharpRepositoryConfiguration.AddRepository(new CacheRepositoryConfiguration("inmemory"));
sharpRepositoryConfiguration.DefaultRepository = "inmemory";
var repo = sharpRepositoryConfiguration.GetInstance<Account>().Add(new [] { .... });

return new StructureMapDependencyResolver(sharpRepositoryConfiguration);
```

It uses an `InMemoryCachingProvider` by default, which uses the [`MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) for persistence.  Add a prefix to the `CacheRepositoryConfiguration` constructor if you have more repositories to avoid them stomping on each other.

Comment: Actually it can be viable if you set it to singleton (although I have to admit if feels hacky). The thing that weirds me out is that my mvc controller is not persisting the data, even though the repo is injected into the constructor. This makes me feel like it's creating multiple controllers? But this is another question for another time.

Comment: Double post - I had better clarify. Unit testing works completely fine, it was when I wanted to actually use the repositories in a real environment I was having issues. I used Moq to mock up the repository returns. The reason is, is because MVC creates a new controller instance per request, so I was creating a new InMemoryRepository every request.